# Linker error to copy constructor of std::function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

When attempting to compile my code, the linker spews out an undefined reference error- to the copy constructor of std::function. I don't understand how this is even possible. Here is the SSCCE I have created.

```
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

namespace Wide {
    namespace Codegen {
        class Statement { public: virtual ~Statement() {} };
        class Expression : public Statement {};
        class IfStatement  : public Statement {};
        class Generator {
        public:
            virtual IfStatement* CreateIfStatement(Expression* expr, Statement* t, Statement* f) = 0;
            virtual IfStatement* CreateIfStatement(std::function<Expression*()>, Statement*, Statement*) = 0;
        };
    }
    namespace LLVMCodegen {
        class Statement { public: virtual ~Statement() {} };
        struct Expression : Statement {};

        class IfStatement : public Statement, public Codegen::IfStatement {
        public:
            IfStatement(std::function<LLVMCodegen::Expression*()> cond, LLVMCodegen::Statement* tbr, LLVMCodegen::Statement* fbr) {}
        };
        Expression* AssertExpression(Wide::Codegen::Expression* e) {
            return dynamic_cast<Wide::LLVMCodegen::Expression*>(e);
        }
        Statement* AssertStatement(Wide::Codegen::Statement* e) {
            return dynamic_cast<Wide::LLVMCodegen::Statement*>(e);
        }
        class Generator : public Codegen::Generator {
        public:            
            IfStatement* CreateIfStatement(Codegen::Expression* expr, Codegen::Statement* t, Codegen::Statement* f) {
                return CreateIfStatement([=] { return expr; }, t, f);
            }
            IfStatement* CreateIfStatement(std::function<Codegen::Expression*()> cond, Codegen::Statement* tr, Codegen::Statement* fls) {
                return new IfStatement([=] { return AssertExpression(cond()); }, AssertStatement(tr), fls ? AssertStatement(fls) : nullptr);
            }
        };
    }
}

int main() {
    Wide::LLVMCodegen::Generator g;
}
```

Attempting to compile this sample gives

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall std::function<class Wide::Codegen::Expression * __cdecl(void)>::function<class Wide::Codegen::Expression * __cdecl(void)>(class std::function<class Wide::Codegen::Expression * __cdecl(void)> &)" (??0?$function@$$A6APAVExpression@Codegen@Wide@@XZ@std@@QAE@AAV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: class Wide::Codegen::IfStatement * __thiscall Wide::LLVMCodegen::Generator::CreateIfStatement(class std::function<class Wide::Codegen::Expression * __cdecl(void)>,class Wide::Codegen::Statement *,class Wide::Codegen::Statement *)" (?CreateIfStatement@Generator@LLVMCodegen@Wide@@QAEPAVIfStatement@Codegen@3@V?$function@$$A6APAVExpression@Codegen@Wide@@XZ@std@@PAVStatement@53@1@Z)
```

If you take away all virtual functions from `Wide::LLVMCodegen::Statement`, the code sample compiles as it should. How can I resolve this error without introducing the fairly crippling issue of not being able to use an interface?

Comment: Works fine with [gcc 4.8.1](http://ideone.com/hasoQp).

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that it was a compiler bug.

Comment: Works fine with both versions of both gcc and clang.

Comment: The issue isn't whether or not it's a compiler bug, but how I'm going to work around it

Comment: It's attempting to link against a copy constructor which takes its parameter by reference to non-const. Try making `cond` const or something, in `CreateIfStatement`, to force it to choose the canonical copy constructor which takes by reference to const.

Comment: That worked for me- interesting solution, but it worked. Post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that by making the parameter `const`, I could dodge this error.